# Limit without L'Hôpital's theorem or squeeze theorem

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

I was trying to solve: 
**$$\lim _{x\to 0^-}\left(\frac{\sin\frac{-3}{x}-4}{x}\right)$$**
from the squeeze theorem we know that
$$3\le \sin\frac{-3}{x}\le -3$$
My question since limit is approaching to left side of $0$. Should I apply limit on both side of 
like 
$$\lim _{x\to 0^-}-3\le \sin\frac{-3}{x}\le \lim _{x\to 0^-}3$$
or one side 
$$\lim _{x\to 0^-}-3$$
if there any other easy evaluation possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't squeeze it but you can estimate the given term by something divergent as follows for $x<0$:

$$\frac{\sin\left(-\frac{3}{x}\right)-4}{x}\stackrel{x<0\Rightarrow|x|=-x}{=}\frac{4+\sin\left(\frac{3}{x}\right)}{|x|}\geq \frac 3{|x|}\stackrel{x\to 0^-}{\longrightarrow}+\infty$$

Comment: is there any reason why we cannot use squeeze therom?

Comment: @FeemoFellow : Squeezing is used to show that an expression has a FINITE limit. But here you have an expression which is diverging to $+\infty$ for $x\to 0^-$. So, you cannot squeeze it because it is "running away" to $+\infty$.

Comment: @FeemoFellow : Maybe the graph can convince you that a proper squeezing is not possible.
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%28sin%28-3%2Fx%29-4%29%2Fx

Comment: thanks sir last question how you evaluate 4+sin(3/)=3 ? this is the actual thing I want to learn

Comment: But what you can do is the following (but this is hardly "squeezing") in the sense of the word: $$\frac 5{|x|}\geq\frac{4+\sin\left(\frac{3}{x}\right)}{|x|}\geq \frac 3{|x|}$$
But, since the lower bound goes to $+\infty$, you do not need the upper bound.

Comment: @FeemoFellow :Concerning your last question:
We know $-1\leq \sin \frac 3x \leq 1 \Rightarrow 3 \leq 4+\sin \frac 3x \leq 5$.

Comment: thanks sir in order to take the limit from left hand side can I also take 5/x since Both 3/x and 5/x are diverging

Comment: But the limit for $\frac 5{|x|}$ does not really help in this case. It only says, there is a function which bounds the given one from above, and this function diverges to $+\infty$. But this gives us no information about what the given function does. That's why the lower bound is the really important one here.

Comment: thanks sir it was a great help

Comment: @FeemoFellow : You are welcome. It was my pleasure :-)

Comment: I am certain that you have got the best teacher

Comment: I think you may like the picture:
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%28sin%28-3%2Fx%29-4%29%2Fx%2C+%283%29%2F%7Cx%7C%2C+%285%29%2F%7Cx%7C%2C+x%3D-0.5..0

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can bound $\sin(\frac{-3}{4})$ by $-1$ and $1$, ie, $-1\leq \sin(\frac{-3}{4})\leq 1$. So your function, say $f(x)$ is bounded by $g(x)$ and $h(x)$, where $g(x)=\frac{-5}{x}$ and $h(x)=\frac{-3}{x}$, ie,
$$g(x)\leq f(x) \leq h(x)$$

But, the limit of both $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ is $\infty$ as $x \rightarrow 0$, so $f(x)$ must also have the limit of $\infty$ as $x \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: a good approach also thank sir